# Using koa can't set uid-safe token in a cookie

Tags: cookies, koa

I'm using node version 5.0.0, uid-safe version 2.0.0, and koa version 1.1.2

My problem is I'm trying to generate a token with uid-safe and save it as a cookie and then retrieve the cookie and display it in the console.

The program generates the token ok but when I try to set the cookie using

```
this.cookies.set(cookieName, token);
```

it just seems to hang no error message is shown.
and the line after which should display "Got past setting the cookie never gets shown".

```
var koa = require('koa');
var app = module.exports = koa();
var uid = require('uid-safe');

app.use(function *() {
    var cookieName = 'koa.sid';
    uid(18).then(function(token) {
        console.log("token: " + token);  // token: 0bk6D3CFtGJgQ5HmiANFnosC
        this.cookies.set(cookieName, token);
        console.log("Got past setting the cookie"); // this never gets shown
        retrievedToken = this.cookies.get(cookieName);
        console.log(cookieName + ': ' + retrievedToken);
    });
});

if (!module.parent) app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.cookies.set()` throws an exception, but since you don't have a `.catch()` clause in your promise chain, that exception gets lost (`uid(18).then(...).catch(...)`).

The exception is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
```

That's because `this` is not the right context (for all intents and purposes, you should consider it to be undefined if you don't bind the callback function passed to `.then()`).

Since you're using a generator function, you can use `yield` instead:

```
app.use(function *(next) {
  var cookieName = 'koa.sid';
  var token      = yield uid(18);

  console.log("token: " + token);
  this.cookies.set(cookieName, token);
  console.log("Got past setting the cookie");
  ...
  yield next;
});
```

Also, `this.cookies.get()` won't work because (AFAIK) it will only get cookie values passed in through the request (whereas you're setting the cookie as part of the response).